# SQL Get Second Record

Tags: sql-server

I am looking to retrieve only the second (duplicate) record from a data set. For example in the following picture:

[image]

Inside the UnitID column there is two separate records for 105. I only want the returned data set to return the second 105 record. Additionally, I want this query to return the second record for all duplicates, not just 105.

I have tried everything I can think of, albeit I am not that experience, and I cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which of those 2 rows is the second?, what column are they ordered by?

Comment: I'd guess that it's by the first column, JobUnitK(whatever the rest is), but that's purely speculation.

Comment: @Lamak my apoogies, they will be sorted by `order by UnitID asc, DispatchDate asc`

Comment: But in the sample data both rows have the exact `DispatchDate`

Comment: That's still not specific enough - you have multiple rows that have the same UnitID and DispatchDate, you need to add something unique to your `order by` clause.

Comment: Please don't use screen shots. No one can copy and paste, or search, or display your question in search results properly. And if your post is syndicated on other sites, there may be no image capacity present.

Comment: @Lamak The answer below was what I was looking for.

Comment: That's great. Even though it isn't returning the whole row as the question seemed to be asking and also doesn't really return a "second" row, since there was no ordering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`GROUP BY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) for this.

Here's an example: (I can't read your first column name, so I'm calling it `JobUnitK`

```
SELECT MAX(JobUnitK), Unit
FROM JobUnits
WHERE DispatchDate = 'oct 4, 2015'
GROUP BY Unit  
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I'm assuming `JobUnitK` is your ordering/id field. If it's not, just replace `MAX(JobUnitK)` with `MAX(FieldIOrderWith)`.

Comment: This worked exactly as I hoped! I have never seen the `HAVING` term before. So before I blindly take code from the internet can you explain that to me?

Comment: @ChaseErnst Sure, `HAVING` works like `WHERE` but for `GROUP BY`. Basically, it only returns rows where the `GROUP BY` clause would return more than 1 row.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense! Thank you. I can accept the answer in 5 minutes.

Comment: @ChaseErnst No problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: would there be any way to switch what record this query returns? It returns the top record, but I need the second one.

Comment: @ChaseErnst Sure, just switch `MAX` to `MIN`.

Comment: @ChaseErnst No problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server 2005 and up, you can use the [`Row_Number` windowing function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH DupeCalc AS (
   SELECT
      DupID = Row_Number() OVER (PARTITION BY UnitID, ORDER BY JobUnitKeyID),
      *
   FROM JobUnits
   WHERE DispatchDate = '20151004'
   ORDER BY UnitID Desc
)
SELECT *
FROM DupeCalc
WHERE DupID >= 2
;
```

This is better than a solution that uses `Max(JobUnitKeyID)` for multiple reasons:

- There could be more than one duplicate, in which case using `Min(JobUnitKeyID)` in conjunction with `UnitID` to join back on the `UnitID` where the `JobUnitKeyID` <> MinJobUnitKeyID` is required.
- Except, using `Min` or `Max` requires you to join back to the same data (which will be inherently slower).
- If the ordering key you use turns out to be non-unique, you won't be able to pull the right number of rows with either one.
- If the ordering key consists of multiple columns, the query using `Min` or `Max` explodes in complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RANK` function. Rank the rows `OVER` PARTITION BY UnitId and pick the rows with rank 2 .

For reference -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms176102.aspx

Comment: `Rank` over `PARTITION BY UnitId` may fail because `Rank` requires an `ORDER BY` clause, and the ordered by column(s) could have duplicates themselves, thus requiring `Row_Number` instead (not even `Dense_Rank` will solve all the duplicates because the first set could be duplicate, too). For similar reasons, `= 2` is incorrect, it must be `>= 2`. Last, your answer is an incomplete but near-duplicate of another one on the page that goes into more detail.